# How does tkinter grid placement work when using child classes in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

To preface this, I have this working, I was just hoping somebody could explain why the code is behaving the way it is. I'm not understanding the grid system inside of classes very well apparently.

```
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('400x400')

        self.rowconfigure(0, uniform=True, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, uniform=True, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, uniform=True, weight=1)

        self.header_frame = HeaderFrame(self)
        self.header_frame.grid(column=0,row=0)

        self.login_frame = LoginFrame(self)
        self.login_frame.grid(column=0,row=1)

        self.button_frame = ButtonFrame(self)
        self.button_frame.grid(column=0,row=2)

class HeaderFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.columnconfigure(0, uniform=True, weight=1)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='black')
        self.canvas.grid(column=0,row=0)

class loginFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent=parent

        self.columnconfigure(0, uniform=True, weight=1)

        self.entryBox = ttk.Entry(self, width=33)
        self.entryBox.grid(column0,row1)

class ButtonFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent=parent

        self.columnconfigure(0, uniform=True, weight=1)

        self.btn = ttk.Button(self, text='test')
        self.btn.grid(column=0,row=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().mainloop()
```

Now my question comes down to the grid placement. When I call each class to place the items, I specify different grid locations. header_frame.grid(column=0, row=0), login_frame(column=0,row=1), etc. However, the initial App class having a grid placement does not affect the layout of the gui whatsoever. I can place them all on row 0 and they will all still show up on separate rows until I change the grid placement inside of the individual class. I thought my grid inside of the class was being placed inside of cells of the App class, what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You aren't passing the `parent` parameter to the base class in your `__init__()` methods.  Without that parameter, widgets are created as a child of the root window, rather than your intended parent.

Comment: @jasonharper are you saying on the def __init__(self, parent): lines I need to add something? Or in my call to the class from the parent App class?

Comment: edit your `super().__init__()` to `super().__init__(parent)` so the actual tkinter widget knows that you want that parent/master.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Thanks for your help on this. Like I said, I had a working version but it was really bothering me that I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working like I thought it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
class HeaderFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
```

`super().__init__()` is what actually creates the widget. You aren't passing `parent` to `super().__init__())` so the widget will be created as a child of the root window. You need to pass `parent` like in the following example.

```
super().__init__(parent)
```

You need to make a similar change for all of your classes.